# Using #select on either a hash or an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

The values in my hash are either a nested hash:

```
test_multiple_hash = { test: { another_test: 123 } }
```

or an array of hashes:

```
test_multiple_hash = { test: [{ another_test: 123 }, { another_test: 124 }] }
```

After having fetched a value, I need to use #select to find specific nested hashes:

```
test_multiple_hash[:test].select { |s| s[:another_test] == 123 }
```

If my hash has only a single hash, then `select` doesn't suite my needs unless I convert the single hash into an array.

Is there a better way to find an object by the value to a key when the value to a key in the hash is a single hash or an array of hashes?

Comment: What is `test_multiple_hash`?

Comment: cool, downvote without a reason why?

Comment: What is your expected result with the simpler (nested hash) case?

Comment: it's the value of either of the two possible search results, if you read the key I am trying to select to you should relate it to the example of hashes i was referring to...

Comment: I want to assure that the search result (either simple case or array of hashes) is in fact the object I am expecting... the result would be the nested hash itself, that will contain more fields

Comment: Is there only one hash within the array that has the expected condition (say the value to the key `:another_test` is `123`)? If so, do you actually want that single hash instance that matches rather than getting an array?

Comment: This seems pretty clear to me.  I've edited your question pretty heavily to better reflect what I think you mean.  If I have erred, then will you please revert my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
[my_hash[:test]].flatten.select { |s| s[:another_test] == 123 }
```

Comment: This suite my needs for this particular problem, other solutions also do the trick but this one looks cleaner for the problem above! thanks for your suggestion! I am now applying it =)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to start with making all the underlying values of common pattern:

```
hash = { test: { another_test: 123 },
         test2: { test: [{ another_test: 123 }, { another_test: 124 }] }
       }

hash.map { |k, v| [k, [*v]] }.to_h # now all of them are arrays.
```

And then do whatever you want, assuming that the values are definitely arrays, e. g.:

```
hash.map do |k, v|
  [k, [*v]]
end.to_h[:test].select do |s| 
  s[:another_test] == 123
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does help me solve my problem and helped me realise efficient ways of dealing with different data models throughout my codebase...

Answer (score 1):

The method [Kernel#Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) will convert its argument to an array:

```
2.2.1 :002 > Array(1)
 => [1]
```

unless the argument already is an array; then it returns the argument unchanged:

```
2.2.1 :003 > Array([1])
 => [1]
```

So you can use the Array function to force `test_multiple_hash[:test]` to be an array:

```
Array(test_multiple_hash[:test]).select { |s| s[:another_test] == 123 }
```

The result of #select will always be an array, even if `test_multiple_hash[:test]` was not an array.